# Is there any way to store file thumbnails in each partition? (XFCE)

Tags: xubuntu, external-hdd, thunar, thumbnails

Is it possible to persuade Xubuntu to store file thumbnails for an external hard drive into the drive itself instead of the home folder?

Benefits include avoiding the ~/.thumbnails folder to get too large and avoiding too much writing on an SSD internal drive.

The external hdd in question is where I store several years worth of photography. I think even if I disable thumbnails in Thunar, applications like gthumb still cause them to be generated.